# AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, hello.js

I am using hello.js to sign in Microsoft Graph.

First I initialized by

```
hello.init({
    msft: {
      id: myAppId,
      oauth: {
        version: 2,
        auth: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
      },
      scope_delim: ' ',
      form: false
    },
  },
  { redirect_uri: window.location.href }
);
```

Then I signed in successfully in my app

```
hello('msft').login({ scope: 'User.Read' })
```

This is what hello.js saved in localStorage after signing in.

```
{
  "msft": {
  "access_token":"aLongToken",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3599,
    "scope":"basic,User.Read",
    "state":"",
    "session_state":"f034f785-f8d0-4cec-aab4-88559c9d93dd",
    "client_id":"a91e6907-2b6e-4793-848d-633e960e809d",
    "network":"msft",
    "display":"popup",
    "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3006/login",
    "expires":1501800737.361
  }
}
```

However, when I try to refresh the access_token

```
hello('msft').login({
  display: 'none',
  response_type: 'id_token token',
  response_mode: 'fragment',
  nonce: 'my-app',
  prompt: 'none',
  scope: 'User.Read',
  login_hint: 'Rose.Bukater@company.com',
  domain_hint: 'organizations'
})
```

I got the error

> AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed
>   in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in
>   the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet
>   Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request
>   is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint
>   (login.microsoftonline.com).

I am using Chrome.

Found [this issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/323) on GitHub. But still didn't figure out how to refresh correctly.

---

UPDATE:

After disable **Allow Implicit Flow** at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, now I even failed to log in. So this is not the correct solution. hello.js saved this error in the localStorage:

```
{
  "msft": {
    "error": {
      "code":"unsupported_response_type",
      "message":"AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application\r\nTrace ID: 1dc20dd0-cab3-41b5-9849-2a7e35d60700\r\nCorrelation ID: caacce8f-6763-405d-a840-70c24d5306d4\r\nTimestamp: 2017-08-04 21:56:42Z"
    },
    "error_description":"AADSTS70005: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application\r\nTrace ID: 1dc20dd0-cab3-41b5-9849-2a7e35d60700\r\nCorrelation ID: caacce8f-6763-405d-a840-70c24d5306d4\r\nTimestamp: 2017-08-04 21:56:42Z",
    "state":"",
    "client_id":"a91e6907-2b6e-4793-848d-633e960e809d",
    "network":"msft",
    "display":"popup",
    "redirect_uri":"http://localhost:3006/login",
    "scope":"basic,User.Read"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. My code in the question is totally correct. The reason causing this issue is because in our company each person has two emails:

- one is full name email **Rose.Bukater@company.com**
- one is alias email **rosebuk@company.com**, which is the property `userPrincipalName`

For `login_hint` below, it has to be the alias email.

```
hello('msft').login({
  display: 'none',
  response_type: 'id_token token',
  response_mode: 'fragment',
  nonce: 'my-app',
  prompt: 'none',
  scope: 'User.Read',
  login_hint: 'Rose.Bukater@company.com',  // <- has to be rosebuk@company.com
  domain_hint: 'organizations'
})
```

Comment: Did you figure out why and how to know which one is the one to use? Presumably the User object in your case contains both email addresses -
 which property is the right one?

Comment: @mikenelson it is `userPrincipalName`

Answer (score 3):

It happens when the cookie of the user currently connected for login.microsoftonline.com has expired. The way we handle it is we redirect the user to sign in page with current page as redirecturi parameter.

Comment: hello.js saved the token in localstorage. I didn't see it is using cookies. And actually to test refresh token. I did it just 20s after signing in. So I don't think anything is expired. Maybe something else cause this?

Comment: If you have a look at the first token you're getting, does it contain a refresh token? Are you leveraging explicit Grant or implicit flow?

Comment: I think I only have a refresh token, I added in my question.

Comment: To me it looks like you're using the implicit flow and this is why you don't get a refresh token and only an access token

Comment: After disabling it, now I even cannot log in. This is a single page app, the implicit flow has to be turned on, right? If yes, then any other way I can refresh the token?

Comment: When it comes to auth for a SPA app you have two choices:
- implicit, doesn't require any backend, very simple, doesn't give you a refresh token
- authorization code flow, requires a secret and most of the time people rely on a backend to hold that. provides a refresh token.
you can read more about that on that blog post https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/OpenID-Connect-Flows